# Understanding the use of "while True" in a control flow Python generator function

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the use of the `while True` statement  in the following Python code. It uses a generator and appears in the 'Visualizing the flow' section of this [webpage](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/).

The code is an example that attempts to solve [Project Euler problem 10](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10). Here, we use `get_primes` with a start value of 3. The `solve_number_10` function calls `get_primes` until it hit the last prime number up to 2,000,000.

```
def solve_number_10():
# She *is* working on Project Euler #10, I knew it!
    total = 2
    for next_prime in get_primes(3):
        if next_prime < 2000000:
            total += next_prime
        else:
            print(total)
            return

def get_primes(number):
    while True:
        if is_prime(number):
            yield number
        number += 1
```

The author writes:

> If a generator function calls return or reaches the end its
>   definition, a `StopIteration` exception is raised. This signals to
>   whoever was calling `next()` that the generator is exhausted (this is
>   normal iterator behavior). **It is also the reason the `while True:` loop
>   is present in `get_primes`. If it weren't, the first time `next()` was
>   called we would check if the number is prime and possibly yield it. If
>   `next()` were called again, we would uselessly add 1 to number and hit
>   the end of the generator function (causing `StopIteration` to be
>   raised).** Once a generator has been exhausted, calling `next()` on it
>   will result in an error, so you can only consume all the values of a
>   generator once. The following will not work:

```
our_generator = simple_generator_function()
    for value in our_generator:
        print(value)

print(next(our_generator))
```

Why do we hit the end of the generator function in the absence of the `while true` statement? What exactly do we need to declare as `true`? Is it that the `number`is less than 2,000,000? I do not think this is the case, since `solve_number_10` takes care of that. I don't understand why the generator function would end in the second iteration, given the absence of the `while True` statement, if there is a long way until `number` hits 2,000,000.

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain the bolded text in the yellow quote block. Thank you!

Comment: It's a generator which should return many values. Without a loop or recursion there is only a one-time return possible. So while true makes it infinite. You can call it as many times you want. The increment-stuff is just an effect of that ordering of operations.

Comment: Generation of values ends when generator implicitly returns. When body is wrapped with `while True`, it _never_ implicitly returns.